# How to use custom option form grunt task in loops

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

I am using grunt-assemble, in grunt task I add custom option of language by following below documentation

[assemble docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOQAq.png)
and below is the image of my grunt task
[grunt  task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZALi.png)

```
{{language}}
{{#withSort pages "data.navSortOrder"}}
{{langugae}}
{{#is data.showInNav true}}
<li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>

{{language}}


{{/is}}
{{/withSort}}
```

In above  code language outside the withsort block is outputting the expected result but in withsort block language option isn't outputting anything

Answer (score 0):

When using block helpers like `withSort`, handlebars changes the depth of the data. To access the previous depth (where `language` is), you can use the `..` syntax. If you know `language` will always be at the root of the context, then you can use the `@root` keyword:

```
{{language}}
{{#withSort pages "data.navSortOrder"}}
{{../language}}
{{@root.language}}
{{#is data.showInNav true}}
<li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>

{{language}}


{{/is}}
{{/withSort}}
```

Also... when updating your example, I noticed that the second "language" was spelled as "langugae".

Comment: {{@root.language}} not working at any level
{{../../language}} this  is working